# Compiling App Wrappers with GNUStep

Tags: objective-c, grails-orm, gnustep

I am following the directions verbatim as on the GNUStep website.  Here's my make file.

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

APP_NAME = FirstApp

FirstApp_OBJC_FILES = main.m \
MyController.m

FirstApp_MAIN_MODEL_FILE = FirstApp.gorm

FirstApp_RESOURCE_FILES = FirstApp.gorm

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/application.make
```

Here are the contents of the directory (noted that in the tutorial there is no mention of creating a main.m file.  I assumed this was autogenerated somehow. If this is an omission on the tutorial writers part please let me know. Also what should the main.m file contain.

```
FirstApp.gorm  GNUmakefile  MyController.h  MyController.m  MyController.m~
```

I compiled by switching to the directory and running make and this is the output I recieved.

```
This is gnustep-make 2.6.1. Type 'make print-gnustep-make-help' for help.
Making all for app FirstApp...
 Creating FirstApp.app/....
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `obj/FirstApp.obj/main.m.o', needed by `FirstApp.app/./FirstApp'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [internal-app-run-compile-submake] Error 2
make[1]: *** [FirstApp.all.app.variables] Error 2
make: *** [internal-all] Error 2
```

Now I can see that this has to do with the main.m file, but from the output I am not sure where to go from here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to GNUstep. Could I have mistakenly deleted the creation of it when working with gorm?

Answer (score 0):

I found an aweomse tutorial here a few hours later.  Here is the link.  The Main file should basically look like this:

```
#include <AppKit/NSApplication.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) 
{
   return NSApplicationMain (argc, argv);
}
```

here's the link

http://gnustep.made-it.com/GSPT/xml/Tutorial_en.html#AEN412